# Which function should be used for AES-256 encryption from AES.h in CFB mode in C++ application?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

I have to write C++ application for encryption using the AES-256 algorithm.
I am using OpenSSL library for encryption. 
I have seen in aes.h there is function called `AES_cfb128_encrypt`, but there is no function mentioned for AES-256.

Could you please let me know which function to be used for AES-256 encryption in CFB mode?

Answer (score 2):

The 128 in `AES_cfb128_encrypt` refers to the segment size of the CFB mode and not the key size of AES. The function takes a key struct that is independent of the key size. So you can use every possible key size with this: 128, 192 and 256 bit.

CFB mode is one of the modes that is parametrized. It means that AES is applied in differently sized segments than the block size (128-bit fixed). As you may note, there are also `AES_cfb8_encrypt` and `AES_cfb1_encrypt`.

So there are three different numbers to keep track of:

- AES block size: 128 bit
- AES key size: 128, 192, 256 bit
- CFB segment size: 1, 8, (16, 32, 64), 128 bit